# How can I create unique variables when using mixins as functions in LESS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I needed to create a function for some big color work on my Bootstrap variables.  Unfortunately LESS doesn't allow you to create functions that can be called like theirs (ex. @myvar: darken(@color, 20%);).

The option provided on the doc site is to use a mixin that returns a variable. This worked well for me when I used it where the variable was declared as the property value, but I need to run my new mixin on many variables in the Bootstrap variable.less file. If I call the mixin multiple times there, it always returns the first color.

Part that works:

```
.mixin(@color) {
  @var: @color;
}
.caller-1 {
  .mixin(blue);
  color:@var;
}
.caller-2 {
  .mixin(red);
  color:@var;
}
```

CSS

```
.caller-1 {
  color:blue;
}
.caller-2 {
  color:red;
}
```

What does not work:

```
.mixin(blue);
@color-1: @var; // My value is now blue

.mixin(red);
@color-2: @var; // My value is also blue
```

I thought I could get around this by building a unique variable in the mixin, but I can't find anyway to build one.

```
.mixin(@color; @num)
  @var+@{num}: @color;
}
.mixin(blue; 1);
@color-1: @var1;

.mixin(red; 2);
@color-2: @var2;
```

Any idea on how to create a variable name in a mixin or other ideas on how to make one work like the LESS functions?

Comment: Maybe it would be more helpful to say that the only Bootstrap file I can change is the variables.less file. We have many projects using the same core Bootstrap files, each with their own variables.less file. I wouldn't want to call the mixin in every location the variable is called. The variable may also be used in another mixin, so I don't really want to define a property.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define variables dynamically in LESS right now, but you can dynamically define selectors (as you probably knew). I will just give an example of that and leave it to you to apply it to the color/variables issue.

```
.towerMaker (@index) when (@index > 0)  {
   .block-@{index} {
      z-index: @{index};
    }

  .towerMaker(@index - 1);
}
.towerMaker (7);
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue, but thanks for looking at the problem. I need to be able to change the value of variables as they are called in many places instead of applying the mix each place the variables are used. The variables I am using can also be changed in other mixins, so I don't want to deal with defining the property.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are actually constants, and their scope is based only on context (where they appear in the block doesn't matter). It's only different when you call it within a selector block because of context. When you call the mixin at top-level, you define `@var` once for that level and it won't be overriden.

If you have to use variables, I suggest you try to find a solution taking advantage of the context. <strike>For example, you might be able to try something with mixin guards `& when(condition) {...}`</strike> (it's actually even simpler, as @seven-phases-max commented below). This is a way to run a mixin outside the context of a selector but still inside a context (updated example):

```
& {
  .mixin(red);
  .test1 { color: @var; }
}
& {
  .mixin(blue);
  .test1 { color: @var; }
}
```

You actually *can* define functions that will be *called* using Less by your Less runtime, but they can't be *defined* using Less. This is possible if you run your processor using Node.js, for example. But it's quite a hack and not trivial since you have to write them in JavaScript and wrap values in undocumented `less.js` types.

You can also call core JavaScript enclosing it within backticks (this is also undocumented). It's good for small blocks of code and for core functions:

```
length: unit(`Math.log(@{value})`, px);
```

If you run your Less processor from a Node.js app you can call your own functions that way.

Comment: Btw., no need in guards for the `&` scope case, see https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/538#issuecomment-31346194

Comment: Great comment. Thanks. The example also includes another way of calling functions in the 'same scope'.

Comment: Your "length" example calls javascript in a less function. Can you call a less function in the javascript?

Comment: You can via the `less` object, but its not trivial. You have to deal with the undocumented built in types (for example, you can't use bare numbers, you have to wrap them in a `less.tree.Value(number)`). The same with colors, collections, etc. and when you are done you have to call the `toCSS()` method to generate the output. The functions are in the `less.tree.functions` collection. For example, you can get the square root of 2 by calling `less.tree.functions.sqrt(less.tree.Value(2))`.

Comment: Are you referring to the custom function and not the backtick method? I can't get it to work with the backticks.

Comment: No. You asked if there was a way to run Less functions in JavaScript (a Node.js app, I assume). Backticks are a way to run core JavaScript when coding in Less. To call Less functions in Less you simply call them directly `length: sqrt(2);`